# Is it possible to access just part of a data path with Python?

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor

I am trying to access just the last few nodes of a data path, however blender tries to execute it when I try to use `split` or similar functions. What is the proper way to do this?

The data: `bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].sequence_editor.sequences_all["Image0001.png"]`

What I want: `sequences_all["Image0001.png"]`

Some things I've tried so far:

The split function:

```
n = bpy.context.selected_sequences
x = n[0]
x = str(x)
print(x.split(str='.'))
```

The problem is blender tries to interpret `split` as an attribute of the image sequence.

I need a dynamic result, as values could change in the first few parts. A way to just capture the "data path" of the selected VSE strip could potentially work as well.

Comment: Somewhat related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42150/splitting-an-objects-data-path-into-hierachal-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script below gets the data path, converts it to a string. Then does the manipulation on it to get the desired part.

I split the string on "*sequence_editor.*" because everything after that (except for the closing bracket) is what you want, a period would also work.

After splitting the string (`string[-1]`) that line gets the last item in the list.
Using your data path the list would look like this:

```
["[bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].", 'sequences_all["Image0001.png"]]']
```

The last item in the list `sequences_all["Image0001.png"]]` only needs to have the trailing bracket removed (last line of the script.)

```
import bpy

path = bpy.context.selected_sequences
string = str(path) #convert data path to string
string = string.split("sequence_editor.") #split string in to a list
string = string[-1] # get last piece
string = string[:-1] # remove last character
print(string)
```

Your problem was you were trying to get the first part of the path `x = n[0]` before turning it in to a string and then splitting it into a list.