# How to get driver's own full data path?

Tags: python, drivers

For example I set a driver to rotation_euler x of a bone called "Bone_L" and it uses a my custom function in driver_namespace. I need to get other half of Bone_L,Bone_R's animation data and sync Bone_L with Bone_R.So I need Bone_L's own full data path.

if I simply copy full data path by right clicking bone's rotation column and click "Copy Full Data Path", I can get this info.

bpy.data.objects["Armature"].pose.bones["Bone_L"].rotation_euler[0]

I need 3 words of this data path. "Armature","Bone_L", and "rotation_euler[0]".
I am gonna use those 3 words to access other half of Bone_L. If I can get those 3 words, I can access animation data of Bone_R like this.

```
armaturename = "Armature"
bonename = "Bone_L"[:-1]+"R"
transform = "rotation_euler"
xyz = 0

Bone = bpy.data.objects[armaturename].pose.bones[bonename]
Transformation = Bone.path_from_id(transform)
Value = Fcurves.find(Transformation, index=xyz)

Scene_Name = bpy.context.scene.name
framenumber = bpy.data.scenes[Scene_Name].frame_current

KeyframeValue = Value.evaluate(framenumber)
return KeyframeValue
```

Is there any way to get Bone_L's full data path inside its driver function?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42150/splitting-an-objects-data-path-into-hierachal-list

Comment: thank you. I will use the function before using that I need to know how to get the path inside Bone_L. Do you know how?  I need to split the path to use it but I don't know how to get this path bpy.data.objects["Armature"].pose.bones["Bone_L"].rotation_euler[0]

Comment: Can you please state this clearly _eg_ you wan't that full data path from what starting point?  Are you using `self` in the driver?

Comment: I need to get Bone_R's animation data and paste it into Bone_L, but I need to get Bone_R data by Bone = bpy.data.objects[armaturename].pose.bones[bonename]. to make it work I need to get both bone's armature name, name of Bone_L and transformation name of Bone_L. I am using self but it only gives me Bone_L's name or it gives me the path? I know self.name gives me a name.

Comment: How about `repr(self)` then?  As for what it's driving, maybe create a wrapper method

Comment: how to use repr()? I googled it but I couldn't understand how.

Comment: I quit using drivers. It's much easier to use just normal functions to control bone animations and it makes easier to manage all script controlled bones. it was hard to find which bones have drivers.